# A New Source of Stalhrim: Baldor Iron-Shaper just keeps saying "Terrible times"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

What can I do to keep Baldor Iron-Shaper from repeating "Terrible times" rather than advancing me to the next stage in the quest?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/292772/294514), you have to defeat Miraak first.

Answer (score 2):

So, at some point (I'm unsure exactly when, as it has been ages since I played with this DLC), you receive the quest to go and defeat Miraak once and for all. Upon receiving this quest, you will be unable to accept new missions from the Skaal, nor will you be able to advance any missions they may have already given you. You must first defeat Miraak, as this is the conclusion of the main questline for the DLC. Once you have done so, you will be free to complete any other quest you have with them and begin accepting new quests from them.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling the DLC which appeared to have fixed the issue.  My old save progress was unaffected which was a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ This is PC, but perhaps it would also work on consoles.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixable if you are on the PC by using this [console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:A_New_Source_of_Stalhrim):

> setstage DLC2SV02 40
>    Then wait for Baldor Iron-Shaper to get to the Abandoned Lodge before rescuing him.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work.  The only thing that appears to work is stage 200, but that appears to end the quest completely.  I don't want to end it.  I want to play through it.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin is balor moving to the cabin with that command?  What exactly does not work about it?  You'll need to provide more info.

Comment: He continues to just stand at the sharpening stone and say the same thing.  I've tries using setstage on all stages in that wiki and 200 is the only one that does anything at all.