# Why can't I talk to Baldor Iron-Shaper?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I have defeated the Thalmor on the ship and gotten the map for the quest "A New Source of Stahlrim," but when I try to take the map back to Baldor, it won't let me talk to him.  Instead, he just does the normal NPC dialogue thing, where he says random things and doesn't let you actually tell him anything.  Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?  I am tired of going into my inventory to drop or store things I don't need and trying to drop the map and not being able to!

Comment: Actually, I figured it out... I was about to come in and answer my own question lol...

Comment: To whoever closed this as a duplicate: please note that the other question actually has no answer, and someone has provided a link to *my* question on the other question.

Comment: "*To whoever closed this as a duplicate*" I reviewed the question timeline. Back in Nov, 2016, someone initiated a close vote as a dupe, but apparently, you agreed with said close vote, so the question was closed by the Community bot. [The Community bot owns the close vote when an asker agrees with a pending duplicate close vote.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/162827)

Comment: No, I never agreed with the close vote, I never even *knew* there was a close vote until I happened to come back to this question and saw it was closed. I personally do not believe in closing questions because they are duplicates, and will *never* agree with that decision.

Comment: That's weird. The [question timeline](/posts/292752/timeline) says that Community bot (and *only* Community bot) closed this question as a dupe, so the asker must've agreed with a pending close vote/flag as per the meta post, [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/162827). If this was not your intention, I recommend raising this issue at [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not completed the main questline and defeated Miraak, you cannot accept any new missions from the Skaal or complete any missions that you may have already received.